# How do I get rid of white outlines around objects in Blender Internal Render Engine?

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

I am rendering a scene in Blender Internal Render Engine and I am noticing white outlines around certain objects. I can't tell if it is happening everywhere or if there just isn't enough contrast to show the problem on other objects. Regardless, I am trying to figure out why this might be happening and how to stop it from rendering this way.

[image: White outlines rendering]

Comment: Do you have *outline* enabled in the render settings? If not, could be a problem with the compositing setup.

Comment: Its to do with the alpha, check pre-multiplied

Comment: I haven't done any compositing yet. I have no lights in the scene either. The only thing I have enabled is Ambient Occlusion (Add) in the World Tab with Samples turned up to 20. Where in the Render Tab is the outline feature, I must be missing it.

Comment: @BrysonJack *Render settings > Post Processing > Edge* (not called "outline", my bad)

Comment: Where do I find the pre-multiplied option exactly?

Comment: I went to Render Settings>Post Processing>Edge and it is not enabled.

Comment: Are you rendering with a background image? Sometimes this can cause minor problems with BI.

Comment: @BrysonJack could you upload you file? Looking at the downvoted answers seems like this has turned into a guessing game. Your issue could be resolved faster if you shared some more info.

Comment: I would like to post the file but since this is a project that I am doing for client, I don't feel comfortable putting the level "out there". I have a background image on the camera which I used to match the scene to the concept art, but the background image wasn't rendering with it (and isn't supposed to) so maybe Vince's suggestion that it might be bug related is the answer. If I get this problem again on a personal project I will post the file. Thanks to everyone who tried to help. This scene will be rendered elsewhere and not in Blender.

Comment: @BrysonJack I know it's been a year, but (for similar future situations) would it be possible to delete all meshes/textures etc. and only include enough to reproduce the problem (e.g. a dummy cube)?

Comment: When possible I usually do some separate scenes to try to reproduce the problem..it is a bit more challenging to do that during production, but I do understand how important providing a .blend file is when seeking support. I will do better.